# How to get currentProvider HTTP URL?

Tags: web3js

How do I get web3 `currentProvider` HTTP URL? I'm using web3 `1.0.0-beta.34`. I tried many functions and already looked at the docs - but still couldn't find the right way to get the URL of the current HTTP RPC node.

The pseudocode that I'm looking for:

```
if (is_using_http_rpc_fn) {
  return currentProvider.url;
}
```

What functions to call for `is_using_http_rpc_fn` and `currentProvider.url` in above pseudocode?

Comment: I looked for an answer myself, but I don't think that it is possible. When you connect to e.g. `ropsten` using `MetaMask`, MetaMask will connect to a URL like `https://ropsten.infura.io/TOKEN`, where `TOKEN` is unique for the MetaMask application. If you could read out the URL, you'd get the private token, which is why I think that there are security reasons for why this it not possible. What you can do is call `web3.version.getNetwork(result => console.log(result))` to see the [Network version](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#construction_worker-network-check)

Answer (score 2):

Based on @robertdavid's answer I found out that it's now

console.log(web3.currentProvider.host);

Confirmed this works for web3 1.0.0-beta.37

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use:

`web3.currentProvider.connection._url`

Confirmed this works for web3 1.0.0-beta36.